# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, insert

Quiero subir actualizar data y no puedo. PHP:

```
include 'includes/conexion.php';
$mat=$_POST["Id_materia"];
$sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_notas WHERE (Id=?) AND (Id_materia=?); ";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO tbl_notas(Id, Id_materia, Esc1, Des1, Otr1, Trim1, Esc2, Des2, Otr2, Trim2, Esc3, Des3, Otr3, EI, Trim3, Anual, Dic, FebMar, Final) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); ";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
for($k=0; isset($_POST["Id_alumno".$k]); $k+=1){
    $al=$_POST["Id_alumno".$k];
    echo $al . $mat ."\n";
    //echo "(0)";
    for($l=0; isset($_POST["param".$k."_".$l]); $l+=1){//Para escribirlo más facil en sql.
        $currentTrim = ($l >= 0 && $l <= 3) ? 1 : ($l >= 4 && $l <= 7) ? 2 :
                        ($l >= 8 && $l <= 13) ? 3 : ($l - 10);
        $data[$l]=$_POST["param".$k."_".$l];
        $data[$l]=str_replace("\"", "", $data[$l]);//Creo que esto está demás.
        $data[$l]=htmlentities($data[$l]);//Por si alguien hace copy & paste con un comando en algún campo de nota.
        if(isInput($l))//Me fijo si hay notas no válidas y las elimino.
            if(!todosNums($data[$l], $l) || strlen($data[$l])>2 || (int) $data[$l] >10 ||
                !fechaOk($currentTrim, $con))
                    $data[$l]="-1";
            echo " ".$data[$l]." ";
    }echo "\n";
    $query->bind_param("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
        $al, $mat, $al, $mat, $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4],
        $data[5], $data[6], $data[7], $data[8], $data[9], $data[10], $data[11], $data[12],
        $data[13], $data[14], $data[15], $data[16]);
    $query->execute();
}
$query->close();
```

Comment: Agregue por favor el código en formato texto y no en imágenes.

Comment: Ah, perdón no me di cuenta, ahora va...

Comment: Un pequeño fallo que veo en tus dos sentencias es que has añadido un punto y coma `;` de más `(Id=?) AND (Id_materia=?); ";` elimina el penultimo punto y coma `;` y aver que pasa.

Comment: Gracias a los 2!

Comment: @D.Bulten el `;` no estaría de más porque está concatenando dos sentencias: un DELETE y luego un INSERT (algo que puede fallar si esa opción no está activada en la base de datos).

Comment: El error es el del título, igualmente Dev. Joel tenía razón, ahora lo estoy tratando de hacer de otra forma.

Comment: Si esta pregunta ya no te sirve, por favor, bórrala. O si encontraste una solución, ponla como respuesta.

Comment: Ok, es que soy nuevo, gracias por avisar. Solo esperen que encuentre ese botón

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no me habia fijado en ese detalle que estaba contatenando dos sentencias, tienes razon.